# page redirection in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am new to node.js, i am developing a simple application where real time data distribution will occour between students and teacher. The student first login and after authentication from server it will be redirected to student interface.
I am done with all authentication and data distribution stuff, please help me how should i redirect to student.html

```
var ports = 3000;
var portt = 3001;
var express = require('express');
var student = require('express')();
var teacher = require('express')();
var server_s = require('http').createServer(student);
var server_t = require('http').createServer(teacher);
var ios = require('socket.io').listen(server_s);
var iot = require('socket.io').listen(server_t);
var path = require('path');

server_s.listen(ports);
server_t.listen(portt);

student.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
student.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/login.html');
});

teacher.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

teacher.get('/', function(req,res){
        res.sendfile(__dirname + '/mytry.html');
});


ios.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
     var username, password;



socket.on('verify',function(data){
username = data[0];
password = data[1];
//************* Database connection and query *************
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host     : 'localhost',
user     : 'user',
password: 'pswd',
database: 'db'
});

connection.connect();
var qstring = 'SELECT s_id FROM login_student WHERE username='+username+'AND password='+password;
connection.query(qstring, function(err, rows, fields) 
{
    if (err) 
    {   
        console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
            socket.emit('login_failure','database error');
        return;
    }
    console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution);
    if (rows>0) alert('Login Successfull');///// **I want redirection here** 
    else socket.emit('login_failure', 'invalid user name or password');
});

connection.end();
});
});

iot.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('sendlesson', function(lesson){
    ios.sockets.emit('updatelesson', lesson);
});
});
```

Comment: FWIW: you should start using [prepared queries](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#preparing-queries) instead of blindly passing user data to MySQL, that's how SQL injections come into existence.

Answer (score 1):

`socket.io` doesn't have a concept of 'redirect', so you're going to have emit a message signaling your client-side code to redirect:

```
// in your socket.io code
if (rows > 0)
  socket.emit('login_success');
else
  socket.emit('login_failure', 'invalid user name or password');

// in your client-side code
socket.on('login_success', function() {
  location.href = '/student.html';
});
```

(this obviously wouldn't stop anyone from accessing `/student.html` directly, though)

Comment: There is no other way?

Comment: @TalhaMajid not with a setup like that (where you have `socket.io` verifying the user)

Comment: Its redirecting me to same page (that is same contents of localhost:3000 are shown....                                        But URL changes to localhost:3000/Redirect.html It doesn't show me the contents of Redirect.html

Comment: @TalhaMajid you said you wanted a redirect to `student.html`, which my example does. Obviously, that file should exist...